# How can I fire a Javascript event when a text box is changed but not by the user?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, anchor, struts

I have a custom tag STRUTS in a JSP set as standard used to handle the calendar and I can't set any type of event here.

This tag render this HTML : `<A onmouseover="return true" href="javascript:ShowCalendar('data')> (..img..) </A>**`

When you select date on link, this change my text box with the date selected, I need fire my event in this moment.

My textbox struts  tag is this `<html:text  property="data" styleClass="testo10" size="12" maxlength="10"  tabindex="3"/>`

I tried with `onchange` event, but this work only if user do the changes.

I need fire event whenever the textbox is changed whether the user is or not(changes from Javascript for example or from link, like in my case).

How can I do that?

Comment: You can just refactor the function out of the onchange and fire it from JavaScript....

Comment: Plus, you need to add the minimum viable code for reproducing this issue!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fire a javascript event when a text box is changed but not by the users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864310/how-can-i-fire-a-javascript-event-when-a-text-box-is-changed-but-not-by-the-user)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with 'input' event.

```
<input type="text" class="txtTest" value="test" onchange="textChange();" oninput="this.onchange();"/>
```

Here I used jQuery to trigger 'input' event and setTimeout() to just mimic text change dynamically.

```
  function textChange(){
    alert('text change');
  }

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.txtTest').val('new text').trigger("input");
  },2000);
```

JS Bin link [here](https://jsbin.com/benipap/edit?html,js,output)

Basically `.trigger()` method of jQuery help to trigger the event which you want to fire. In this case I'm firing 'input' event of textbox, which in return calling it's own `onchange()` method. Or simple you can directly trigger `change` event also.

### Another Solution

For IE7 support
jQuery 1.x + [textchange plugin](http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event) help to achieve this.

I tried with IE7 Emulation.

```
<input type="text" id="txtTest" value="test"/>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  src="http://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/5/jquery.textchange.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#txtTest').bind('textchange', function (event, previousText) {
    alert(previousText);
});

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#txtTest').val('new text').trigger('textchange','some data');
},3000)

</script>
```

Comment: This answer is really great but I forgot to write that I have to write code compatible with internet explorer 7 and to what I saw on the internet the event on input is not supported ... do you have other solutions?

Comment: Yes, there is workaround find this JSBin [link](https://jsbin.com/benipap/edit?html,js,output) 

Hope this will help

Comment: This solution dont'work,cause event fire only when user directly change input and dont when input is changed by button or link or something else

Answer (score -1):

Bind change event in javascript

```
 document.getElementById('txtbox_id').addEventListener('change', function() {

      alert("text changed"); //or do whatever u want here

    });
```